# script "somescript_name.py" can not be installed because plugin "python" is not loaded in Weechat

Tags: python, weechat

I'm trying to install some script in Weechat but anyone of them I'm getting

```
16:45:56 | script: script "notification_center.py" can not be installed because plugin "python" is not loaded
```

I'm running Mac OS X 10.9.2 and install Weechat using `homebrew`

I have python installed. Can anyone point me out what might be wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `Python` was not include as part of `Weechat` installation and it can't load `Python plugin` there.

So, removing `Weechat` and reinstall using this command:

```
brew install weechat --with-python
```

And for notification_center.py in Weechat you need pync:

```
(sudo) pip install pync
```

Comment: Since at least Weechat v2.2 this is now `brew install weechat --with-python@2`.